# Autotouch webserver with images

Tags: ios, lua, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, autotouch

I'm using autotouch (http://autotouch.me/) on a jailbroken iphone with iOS 8.3 and I'm using the webserver to edit my script. I want to load screenshots taken with the app on my computer via the webserver, but I am having trouble.

I'm taking screenshots using with:

```
screenshot ("images/screenshot1.png", nil);
```

which works and puts the screenshot into the images/ directory inside of the autotouch app. But when I try to view the image, it takes me to IP:8080/file/edit?path=/images/screenshot1.png.
This page gives me a Cocoa 261 error, presumably because it is expecting a lua file instead of a png.
Is there any way to view images on the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Autotouch only recognizes `.bmp` images.

Start by saving your images in `.bmp` format. You can rename any of the files simply by removing the `.jpg` and adding `.bmp`

I know for a fact you can view the images from the `WebServer`. Im assuming the `cocoa` error will go away after that.